# create new col that stores DATEDIFF values back in table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table **library** with '*start_date*', '*end_date*' columns. Values are in DATE format.
How do I add a column '*days*' to **library** such that it stores values from DATEDIFF as INT?
I am looking to update the same table and not create a view.

Thanks!

**p.s.** I am using MySQL workbench v8.0.26

Comment: I do need a column with those values available in the table "Library" at all times. Pls let me know if you have a code that does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for this, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE,
    Days INT AS (DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)) -- Column AS <Expression>
);

INSERT T (StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES ('20210101', '20210701');

SELECT *
FROM T;
```

Gives

| StartDate | EndDate | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 01/07/2021 | 181 |

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/99smZV1Bp37gL9m21Utr8o/0)**

Comment: How do I INSERT date VALUES if I already have them in the table Library? Or is it possible to just INSERT the calculated field as "days" back in the same table?

Comment: For an existing table you'd just need to use the `ALTER TABLE` statement to add a generated column, e.g.: `ALTER TABLE T ADD Days INT AS (DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate));` [Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fE9gg92LWuMEcxZfLJc2mi/0)